# SVG <mask> is not scaling with SVG

Tags: svg, mask, scaling

I'm trying to create an opacity mask over an SVG, but for whatever reason it is not covering the full SVG, and is also not scaling.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/chubbaluv/pen/rNNpjvj

```css
svg {
  postion: absolute;
  }
```

```html
<svg>
<!-- A bunch of paths and groups-->
  <defs>
          <mask id="joined-mask" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <linearGradient id="tran-grad">
             <stop  offset="0" stop-color="#fffff" stop-opacity="0"/>
             <stop  offset="0.3359" stop-color="#fffff"/>
             <stop  offset="0.7499" stop-color="#fffff"/>
             <stop  offset="1" stop-color="#fffff" stop-opacity="0"/>
            </linearGradient>
            <rect fill="url(#tran-grad)" width="1245" height="300"/> 
          </mask>
        </defs>
      </svg>
```

Comment: Instead of masking the svg element you may try to add a rect filled with the gradient at the end of the Plates group. The rect will be cuted by the `clip-path`

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to have a gradient to transparency.